# Python: specify same generic argument type

Tags: java, python, generics, nodes

I am starting to learn Python from Java. I would like to write Python code similar to this line in Java:

```
public BinaryNode(T nodeData, BinaryNode<T> leftChild, BinaryNode<T> rightChild) {}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')
class BinaryNode:

    def __init__(self, nodeData : T, leftChild : BinaryNode = None,
             rightChild : BinaryNode = None):
          self.nodeData = nodeData
          self.leftChild = leftChild
          self.rightChild = rightChild
```

How I should specify that the BinaryNodes passed to `__init__` should have the same type parameter as the `nodeData`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is this important to you? Surely, it's logically sound regardless of that specification. Any type-checker should be fine with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses [Duck-Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

**You don't need to specify type. It will resolve at running time.**

Indeed, in Python you handle objects as they come. Therefore, if you handle your `BinaryNodes` as being of the same type of `nodata` and in some cases it isn't, then an error will occur and you should handle it if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I figured out how to handle this:

```
class BinaryNode:

    def __init__(self, nodeData = None, leftChild = None,
                 rightChild = None):
        if leftChild is not None:
            try:
                assert leftChild.getData().type() is nodeData.type()
            except:
                print("Error: left child is not of proper type")
                exit()
        if rightChild is not None:
            try:
                assert rightChild.getData().type() is nodeData.type()
            except:
                print("Error: right child is not of proper type")
                exit()
        self.nodeData = nodeData
        self.leftChild = leftChild
        self.rightChild = rightChild

    def getData(self):
        return self.nodeData
```

I think this is the best way to do it, since the exceptions are handled at runtime.

Comment: A few things. You could just do an `if-else` instead of the `try-except`. Instead of printing and exiting you could just [raise](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions) an exception.
`raise TypeError('Left child is not of proper type'`.

Comment: @palivek I don't think I could do an `if-else`, since `leftChild.getData()` might create an `AttributeError` if `leftChild` is not of type `BinaryNode`. Raising an exception is a good idea though.

Comment: You could do `if isinstance(leftChild, BinaryNode): ...`.